# How can I download a ZIP file with the Maven dependency plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm trying to download a couple of dependencies from the command line using `dependency:copy -Dartifact=...`

However, one artifact looks like this as dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>xml-schemas</artifactId>
  <version>1.10.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <classifier>public</classifier>
  <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

How can I download this? What are the correct Maven coordinates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are using version 2.7 or later of the dependency plugin.  Then it's

```
-Dartifact=<groupId>:<artifactId>:<version>:<type>:<classifier>
```

There is an example in the `dependency:get` section of the [Maven dependency plugin usage docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html).