# Maven: download a ZIP artifact from Nexus and save the zip in a folder

Tags: maven, nexus

I need to download the latest version of an artifact (zip) from Nexus and just save the zip file an directory.
The file of course must be of the same branch and version.
Is there a suitable plugin for this? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download a ZIP file with the Maven dependency plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173684/how-can-i-download-a-zip-file-with-the-maven-dependency-plugin)

Comment: [Another one , even more explicit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388661/unzip-dependency-in-maven?lq=1)

Comment: I've been trying to do this same thing. The answer in "How can I download a ZIP with the Maven dependency plugin?" did not work.